# Does Android Intune SDK support MSAL?

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I am developing an Android app that uses the Intune App SDK for Android. My application uses MSAL for authentication to Azure AD,  but I was not able to find any information about using the SDK with MSAL, only with ADAL.

Release 6.3.0 (https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-android/releases/tag/6.3.0) notes mention that "App developers wishing to use Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) should be using this version of the Intune SDK for Android at minimum." but besides that, I couldn't find any other relevant information.

I know the iOS SDK supports MSAL since release 11.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android Intune SDK supports use with MSAL.Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android#configure-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal)

ADAL for Android, will no longer receive new feature improvements. Instead, use the new library MSAL for Android,Refer to Github:[Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android#microsoft-authentication-library-msal-for-android)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. 



The link you [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android#configure-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal) points to ADAL and not MSAL. You mean that although only ADAL is mentioned in the documentation, MSAL can be used?


  
My app is using MSAL and I plan to integrate it with Intune. As you mentioned, ADAL is discontinued so I don't want to change MSAL to ADAL only for it to be able to work with intune.